# Draw matrix with colours

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure

I'm working on a college project where I need to draw in a graph the cells of a matrix and fill them with a color depending on its value, but I'm having lots of trouble with the color matrix because I am not able to use it as input of the fill function.

The idea is to get something similar to the image below but with the limitations I add in the coordinates of my code.

[image: expected result]

```
function [ output_args ] = drawMatrix(Table)

[m,n]=size(Table); %Get the size of the matrix;
X = 1-0.5:1:n+0.5; %Array with the X coordinates of each cell. 
Y = 1-0.5:1:m+0.5; %Array with the Y coordinates of each cell.
C = repmat('w',[m,n]); %Color matrix to represent the color of each single cell, originally all in white.
[x,y]=meshgrid(X,Y); %Creates the coordinates of the cells of the matrix.
for a=1:m
    for b=1:n
        if Table (a,b) == 1 
            C(a,b)='b'; % If the value of the original cell is 1, the color is changed to blue.
        end
    end
end
photo = fill(x', y', C)
```

The input matrix is:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0;
 0, 1, 1, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I am getting this error:

> Error using `fill`
> Error in `color/linetype` argument.
>
> Error in `drawMatrix` (line 20)
> `photo = fill(x', y', C);`

Comment: The matrix is Table=[0,0,1,1,0;0,1,1,0,0;0,0,1,0,0;1,0,0,0,0];

Comment: Error using fill
Error in color/linetype argument.

Error in prueba2 (line 20)
photo = fill(x', y', C);

Comment: Is your C matrix Nx3?

Comment: No, it has the same size of the matrix, 5x4 in this case.

Comment: How about getting the yellow color instead of white?

Comment: Yeah, yellow more suitable than white in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you want blue color for ones and yellow color for zeros, this is the opposite of what `imagesc` does by default. So, you need to invert the values in the `Table` matrix and give it to the `imagesc` function.

```
imagesc(~Table)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer section)*.

Thanks to Sardar Usama, I was able to find the solution to the problem. Here is the code:

```
function [ output_args ] = drawMatrix(Table)
colors = [1,1,1;0,0,0]; %RGB colors to use 
%(2 in my case,because only has 2 possible values).
values = [0,1]; %The 2 possible values.
imagesc(Table,values); %Creates an image with the matrix Table and the 
range of values.
colormap(colors); %
axis off;
```